# Controlling a bank of relays

Tags: relay, raspberry-pi, hardware

I have a project that requires me to control a set of relays (up-to 24 of them). The current setup is using [Wago Speedway 767 field-bus modules](http://www.wago.us/products/components-for-automation/wago-speedway-767-series/overview/). I'm just ramping up so I have to either figure out how to communicate with the Wgo modules or I need to find a better alternative.

The Wago modules are really nice, but overly complex for this project. I was hoping for something that I could control via USB or Ethernet since I'm controlling everything with a Raspberry Pi and are limited on GPIO's. The relays will run 24v AC. The benefit of using the Wago was that you didn't need 24 individual signal wires coming from the controller to get the job done.

What is the simplest alternative to the Wago setup that will accomplish what I need to do?

Comment: Why not a Leonardo with '595s and '2803s?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams because I didn't know what that was until I just looked it up. It might work, I'll have to research it more.

Comment: Check also the TPIC6C595: a sort-of combination of an HC595 and an ULN2803.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams looks like I can use the 595's with a set of solid state relays to get the job done. Please convert your comment to an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way to control a lot of outputs using a few is to use one or more [74HC595](http://www.ti.com/product/sn74hc595)s cascaded in order to provide as many outputs as required. The only limits to how many you can cascade are timing requirements and the load of the parallel latching inputs.

In order to actually drive the relays you can use the [ULN2803A](http://www.ti.com/product/uln2803a) Darlington array, provided you can deal with the voltage drop they have. Note that while the ULN2803A does provide a flyback diode, it assumes that all 8 relays connected to it have the same positive supply (which should be connected to the COM pin of the array).

Both of these chips work with 3.3V ('595 as a supply, '2803A as an input) so they can be driven directly by the RPi (after procuring a voltage regulator so that the 3V3 output from the RPi isn't burnt out), but if you want to offload control then it is possible to use a MCU such as the ATmega32U4 (found in the Arduino Leonardo) instead. This requires programming in order to interface the USB connection with the '595s, but will make things much easier for the host.

Comment: Thanks. I ordered a few of the 595's (PN: M74HC595B1R). I will look more into the ULN2803A.